# when I use while(scanf("%s",s)==1) to input strings word by word, the expected output seemed coincidental

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char s[1001];
    char str[1001][1001];
    int j=0;
    while(scanf("%s",s)==1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        {
            if(islower(s[i]))
            s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
            else if(isupper(s[i]))
            s[i]=tolower(s[i]);
            
        }
       
        strcpy(str[j],s);
        j++;
    }
    for (int x = j-1; x>=0; x--)
    {
        printf("%s ",str[x]);
    }
    
   
    return 0;
    
}
```

for this one, I need to ctrl+z twice and enter to get the answer;
but for the one below, I just need an enter to get expected anser.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main() {
    char s[100];
    int flag = 1; // 使用 1 表示第一个单词
    while (scanf("%s", s) == 1) {
        if (flag) {
            flag = 0;
            printf("%lu", strlen(s));
        } else {
            printf(",%lu", strlen(s));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea when I can use this kind of input way. And when it comes to word problem, I think it's easier than fgets, so I do not want to give it up.

Comment: Don't call `strlen` on every single loop iteration.  Call it once, before entering the loop.  Save the result, and use it in the loop test.  Try to develop good coding habits.

Comment: `printf("%lu", strlen(s));` it is wrong. It has to be `printf("%zu", strlen(s));`

Comment: "I just need an enter to get expected anser." What is expected answer? Both programs do different things.

Comment: Allocating a megabyte on the stack with your `str` array is worrisome. Not all systems have a stack that big. Make it `static` or move it out of the function to file-scope.

Comment: In (1) you print after all inputs (after the while), in (2) you print inside the loop thus on each input (inside the while)...

Comment: @yang "I think it's easier than fgets" --> yes easier yet `fgets()` has fewer troubles.  Stop using `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.

Answer (score 2):

`%s` discards leading whitespace and scans non-whitespace. It can't detect a newline.
One solution would be to use a `.` to signal the end of input. Use `strchr` to check for a `.`.
Another solution would be to use a specific string to signal the end of input. `-end-` for example. Use `strcmp` to check for the string. `strcmp` returns `0` when the comparison is an exact match.
There are other solutions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 50
#define FS(x) SFS(x)
#define SFS(x) #x

void swapcase ( char *input) {
    unsigned char *check = ( unsigned char *)input;
    while ( *check) { // not the terminating zero
        if ( isupper ( *check)) {
            *check = tolower ( *check);
        }
        else {
            *check = toupper ( *check);
        }
        ++check;
    }
}

int main ( void) {
    char word[SIZE + 1] = ""; //+1 for terminating zero
    char inputs[SIZE][SIZE + 1] = { ""};
    int count = 0;

    printf ( "enter words (end with a .)\n");
    while ( 1 == scanf ( "%"FS(SIZE)"s", word)) { // scan up to SIZE characters
        swapcase ( word);
        strcpy ( inputs[count], word);
        ++count;
        if ( count >= SIZE || strchr ( word, '.')) {
            break;
        }
    }
    for ( int each = 0; each < count; ++each) {
        printf ( "%s ", inputs[each]);
    }
    printf ( "\n");
}
```

Comment: Better as `unsigned char *check = (unsigned char *)input;` to avoid calling `is...()` and `to...()` functions with a negative value - that is UB.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf()` call will always return 1 (except on EOF signalled by ctrl-z in this case) because even an empty string is a string.

You might include a test for empty string:

```
while( scanf("%s", s) == 1 &&
       *s != 0 )
```

However in the first case, since you are iterating the string character by character in the loop, you may as well read the whole string character by character in a single loop thus:

```
for( int i = 0, ch = 0; 
     ch = getchar() && ch > 0 && ch != `\n` ;
     i++)
{
    s[i] = islower( ch ) ? toupper( ch ) :
                           tolower( ch ) ;
}
   
strcpy(str[j],s);
j++;
```

Noting that there is no need for a `isupper()` test after `islower()`, if the character is not alphabetic, `tolower()` has no effect.

Further, the `s` array is redundant, since you only copy it to `str[j]`, you could write directly to `str[j]`:

```
for( int i = 0, ch = 0; 
     ch = getchar() && ch > 0 && ch != `\n` ;
     i++)
{
    str[j][i] = islower( ch ) ? toupper( ch ) :
                                tolower( ch ) ;
}
   
j++;
```